# Get the width of a <li>

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I would like to get the value of the width of a `li`.

When I do this part of code, I can get the width of a `img`, but when I tried with a `li` element it's "undefined" even if I forced a width for `li` element in the CSS.

It is a part of the code.

```
var items = sliderContainer.find('li'),    
    itemWidth = items[0].width,
```

Comment: why don't you use jQuery `width` to get width of an element?

Comment: Why do you end you code with a , instead of ;?

Comment: @Ladineko Likely part of variable definitions

Comment: @IgorDymov That's what I did, and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

use `width()`

```
items = sliderContainer.find('li');    
itemWidth = items[0].width();
alert(itemWidth);
```

Comment: `items[0]` returns DOM node, that doesn't have `width` method, as far as I remember

Comment: I tried with the `width()` element, but without `[0]` and it works fine. It's really strange, because yesterday I did the same action, and it return an `undefined` width.

Comment: `console.log(items[0]);` and check your console what do u get?? this will work no doubt in that..

Comment: @bipen Yes, when I just type this line it works, but when I add width() it doesn't work, because isn't the good syntax with this element. It must be `items.width();` or `items[0].width;`